# Image caching and performance

Tags: java, performance, caching, awt

I'm currently trying to improve the performances of a map rendering library. In the case of punctual symbols, the library is really often jsut drawing the same image again and again on each location. the drawing process may be really complex, though, because the parametrization of the symbol is really very rich. For each point, I have a tree structure that computes the image about to be drawn. When parameters are not dependant on the data I'm processing, as I said earlier, I just draw a complex symbol several times.

I've tried to implement a caching mechanism. I store the images that have already be drawn, and if I encounter a configuration that has already been met, I get the image and draw it again. The first test I've made is for a very simple symbol. It's a circle whose both shape and interior are filled.

As I know the symbol will be constant in all locations, I cache it and draw it again from the cached image then. That works... but I face two important problems :

- The quality of the drawn symbols is hardly damaged.
- More problematic : the time needed to render the map is reaally higher with caching than without caching. That's pretty disappointing for a cache ^_^

The core code when the caching mechanism is on is the following :

```
if(pc.isCached(map)){
    BufferedImage bi = pc.getCachedValue(map);
    drawCachedImageOnGeometry(g2, sds, fid, selected, mt, the_geom, bi);
} else {
    BufferedImage bi = g2.getDeviceConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(200, 200);
    Graphics2D tg2 = bi.createGraphics();
    graphic.draw(tg2, map, selected, mt, AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(100, 100));
    drawCachedImageOnGeometry(g2, sds, fid, selected, mt, the_geom, bi);
    pc.cacheSymbol(map, bi);
}
```

The only interesting call made in drawCachedImageOnGeometry is

```
g2.drawRenderedImage(bi, AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x-100,y-100));
```

I've made some attempts to use VolatileImage instances rather than BufferedImage... but that causes deeper problems (I've not been able to be sure that the image will be correctly rendered each time it is needed).

I've made some profiling too and it appears that when using my cache, the operations that take the longest time are the rendering operations made in awt.

That said, I guess my strategy is wrong... Consequently, my questions are :

- Are there any efficient way to achieve the goal I've explained ?
- More accurately, would it be faster to store the AWT instructions used to draw my symbols and to translate them as needed ? I make the assumption that it may be possible to retrieve the "commands" used to build the symbol... I didn't find many informations about that on the world wide web, though... If it is possible, that would save me both the computation time of the symbol (that can be really complex, as said earlier) and the quality of my symbols.

Thanks in advance for all the informations and resources you'll give me :-)

Agemen.

EDIT : Here are some details about the graphics that can be rendered. According to the symbology model I'm implementing, graphics can be really simple (ie a filled square with its shape) as well as really complex (A Label whose both shape and fill are drawn with hatches, for instance, and even if a halo around it if I want). I want to use a cache because I'm sure that in most configurations I'll be able to :

- differenciate the parameters that have been used to draw two different symbols of the same source that are styled with the same style.
- be sure that two sources with the same parameters (location excepted) will produce the same symbol for the same style, but at two different locations (only a translation will be needed).

Because of these two points, caching seems to be a good strategy. Moreover, there may be thousands of duplcated symbols to be drawn in the same image.

Answer (score 2):

You are awefully vague about what kind of operations your drawing really entails, so all I can give you are some very general pointers.

1.) Drawing a pre-rendered Image is not necessarily faster than drawing the same Image using Graphics2D operations. It depends a lot on the complexity required to draw the image. As an extreme case consider fillRect() vs. a drawImage() of an Image containing the pre-rendered rectangle (fillRect just writes the destination pixels, where drawImage also needs to copy from a source).

2.) In most cases you *never* want to mess with VolatileImage directly. BufferedImage takes advantage of VolatileImage automatically unless you mess with the Image DataBuffer. If you have many pre-rendered images you may also run out of accelerated video memory and that degrades image drawing performance.

3.) On-the-fly scaling/rotating etc. of a pre-rendered image can be pretty costly (depending on the platform and current graphics transformations).

4.) The 'compatible Image' you create may not really be compatible with the drawing target. You obtain an image compatible with the default screen device, which may not be compatible with the actual target in a multi monitor setup. You may get better results using the actual target components createImage().

EDIT:

5.) Translating the coordinates of a rendering operation *may* alter the destination pixels produced. An obvious case is when the coordinates are non-integers (either in the coordinates themselves or indirectly through the AffineTransform set on the graphics). Also, antialiasing of text and possibly other primitives may be influenced slightly by coordinates (subpixel rendering comes to mind).

---

You could attempt an approach that differentiates on if a symbol is presumably fast or slow to render. The fast ones being rendered directly, while the slow ones are cached. The main problem here is in deciding which ones are fast/slow, I expect this to be non-trivial to decide.

Also, I wonder when you say there are thousands of symbols to be rendered, as I imagine most of them should be clipped away since only a small portion of the graph fits into a Window/Frame? If thats the case, don't bother much with caching. Drawing operations that are completely outside the current clip bounds will be relatively cheap - all the graphics target really does for them is detection if they are completely invisible and when they are just do nothing. If the goal is the produce an image to be saved to disk/printed (whatever) I wouldn't bother much with speeding up the rendering, since this is a relatively rare operation and the actual printing may by far exceed the time needed for rendering the graph anyway.

If none of the above applies to your case, be somewhat careful that your cache does not use more time/memory to decide if a cached version exists than it really saves in rendering time. You also need to take into accound that building a cached image instead of rendering to the target directly does *cost* you some time if that image is never reused. Caching can only gain you some speed if the image is reused *at least once*, preferably many more times.

If you build your symbols from primive operations by combining primitve rendering operation objects (like there is a Rectangle, Halo and Text rendering object subclass), you may want to assign each of them a cost indicator and only cache those symbols that exceed some (to be determined) cost threshhold. Also it may be a good idea to implement a hashCode() for each primitive operation and the symbol itself for fast(er) equals detection.

Comment: I'll add som details about the operations that I may encounter. I'm glad to read your 2.) :-) 3.) My cached images just have to be translated (see my EDIT) 4.) I'll improve this point as fast as possible and let you know.